# How do I get all photos a fan page is tagged in with the Facebook Graph API?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, fan-page, photo-tagging

I was able to write a PHP application which requests an access node for the admin of the FB Fan Page, and then requests an access node to gain access to the fan page itself.

I'm now able to get all photos that were posted to the timeline of the fan page by going to https://graph.facebook.com/GROUP_ID/tagged?access_token=...

However, I actually want the photos the fan page is tagged in. The above url only gives me the photos posted to the time line of the fan page, not the ones in which the page is tagged by other users. According to the developers documentation I could get these by going to https://graph.facebook.com/GROUP_ID/photos?access_token=...

Everything seemed to work this way. I got a photo in which the fan page was tagged (profile picture of the fan page). However, I don't get any other photos in which the fan page is tagged. I tried to tag the fan page in its own photos (posted and tagged by an admin of the fan page) and tagging the fan page in other people's photos, but I only get the one profile photo in which the fan page is tagged.

Is this a permission problem or something else?
When requesting the access tokens I asked for the following permissions:

- offline_access
- read_stream
- manage_pages

Any help would be greatly appreciated.